# Can not union two CassandraJavaRDD<CassandraRow> in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

As there is a limit to query the data from Cassandra, I'm trying to read the data batch by batch using Spark and storing it in a RDD.

And then I'm  adding all the RDD , using union function.

Here is my code .

```
private void getDataFromCassandra(JavaSparkContext sc) {


    CassandraJavaRDD<CassandraRow> cassandraRDD = null ;
    CassandraJavaRDD<CassandraRow> cassandraRDD2  = null;

    While(Some Condition)

     cassandraRDD = CassandraJavaUtil
                .javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("dmp", "table").select("abc", "xyz")
                .where("pid IN ('" + sb + "')");

    if(cassandraRDD2==null){


     cassandraRDD2=cassandraRDD;
    }
    else{
        cassandraRDD2 =  cassandraRDD2.union(cassandraRDD);
    }
}
```

}

But in the union I'm getting the following error.

Type mismatch: cannot convert from JavaRDD to CassandraJavaRDD

Though the Both the RDD's is of similar type.

So 1) shall I apply a Cast as

```
 cassandraRDD2 =  (CassandraJavaRDD<CassandraRow>) cassandraRDD2.union(cassandraRDD);
```

2) Or Change the Type of one of the RDD to JavaRDD

Comment: Where do you set `cassandraRDD2`? It seems it's always a null.

Comment: In the if condition ,I'm assigning cassandraRDD2 to  cassandraRDD.

Comment: How do you execute `null.isEmpty()`? Because this is what your'e doing there

Comment: Yes I forget to change it to if(cassandraRDD2==null) , but then why do i need to cast it ?

Comment: Regardless the problem you're talking about, why do you have the `if` statement as its always true?

Comment: I omitted some part of the code , as the if and else conditon running inside a loop , as once if statement is true , after cassandraRDD2 assigning it to cassandraRDD , it will go in else part. Then the need to cast arises , I hope I'm clear. I made the hanges Just now. Sorry about that.

Comment: The problem is according to [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.html) - The `union()` method returns `JavaRDD<T>` and not your type.

Comment: So which is the best way , Shall I apply a cast , or change the type to JavaRDD<CassandraRow> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem happens because according to the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.html):

> **Method:**   union(JavaRDD other) Return the union of this RDD and another one.
>
> **Return Value**: JavaRDD

And therefore the mismatch.

Because according to [this](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector-java/src/main/java/com/datastax/spark/connector/japi/rdd/CassandraJavaRDD.java):

```
public class CassandraJavaRDD<R> extends JavaRDD<R> {
...
}
```

The `CassandraJavaRDD` class extends `JavaRDD` so you can use:

```
JavaRDD<CassandraRow> cassandraRDD = null;
JavaRDD<CassandraRow> cassandraRDD2 = null;
```

and therefore the return value of the `union()` method will match its type.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer.

Comment: JavaRDD<CassandraRow> cassandraRDD2  = sc.emptyRDD(); 
JavaRDD<CassandraRow> cassandraRDD = sc.emptyRDD();  can I union these two empty RDD as cassandraRDD2 =  cassandraRDD2.union(cassandraRDD); ?

Comment: You should be able to do it.